# Propagate Ti Leaf Plant Cuttings In Water

Tags: succulents, propagation, cuttings, water

Recently from my trip to Hawaii I brought back some Ti Leaf (Red Cordyline) cuttings. On the package it says to soak them in water until they develop roots around 5cm long. I have had them in water for about 1 month and I see no sign of roots or growth. The instructions told me to remove the wax coating on each end of the cuttings so I did that with a knife, I didn't damage the cutting itself.

I replace the water around every 2-4 days and the cuttings aren't rotting or anything like that. What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The Royal Horticultural Society (UK) website says "Prepare 5-7.5cm (1-2in) stem-section cuttings from thicker stems that include a bud. Insert the stem cutting horizontally in the compost with the growth bud just visible at the surface." If there were no buds, or they were covered in wax and that damaged them, you may have been sold a couple of bits of dead stalk.

Comment: Hmm, on the second picture some bumps with green can be seen, are those considered growth buds?

Comment: This is what they would look like if they were growing roots. Maybe you should have removed all the wax. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_P0CTzLjps

Comment: I did removed all the wax, just a few small lumps left on the cuttings. Ill keep them in the water and see if anything happens

Comment: "I did removed all the wax" - but your OP says you only removed the wax from the ends. We can only assume that what you write in the question is true!

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't clarify. The wax was only applied on the ends.

Comment: In the lower photo I see some cracks with green underneath, are these new or were they there already when you bought them?

Comment: These were not there when I bought the cuttings. They appeared about a week ago. I didn't want to get my hopes up so I thought it was just the wood expanding due to being soaked in the water and it ripping the skin open. Could it be a place where roots can grow?

Comment: Well that seems hopeful, I am guessing roots will come out from there pretty soon. Have a little more patience (and confidence!), good luck.

Comment: Thanks, when something happens I'll post an update!